# Rspec: can't convert Array into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to stub a directory that has a wildcard in it (don't know the specific version number that affects the naming scheme of the folder).  I tried using double() and ran into issues so I thought maybe this is a two step process...in my current iteration I'm trying to glob the file with a wildcard accounted for and then check if the directory exists after the fact.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
it "Return 1.5 is Linux OS and correct version" do
    Facter.fact(:kernel).stubs(:value).returns("linux")
    dir = Dir.glob("/opt/athena-*/bin/runner")
    Dir.exist?(dir).and_return(true)
    Facter::Util::Resolution.stubs(:exec).with('runner -version').returns("Version:  1.5")
    Facter.fact(:version).value.should == "1.5"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like you need to stub `Dir.exist?`:

```
Dir.stub(:exist?).with(dir).and_return(true)
```

However `Dir.glob` returns an array. Maybe you only want the first one?:

```
dir = Dir.glob('/opt/athena-*/bin/runner').first
```

It's not clear to me what you are trying to test here.

Comment: I'm trying to see if a file exists in a directory, but the directory changes based on the version of athena, so it could be in `/opt/athena-1.4/bin/runner` or `/opt/athena-3.6/bin/runner`

Comment: Still confused--how does this relate to RSpec?

Comment: I have testcases that need to see if this directory exists as part of their test.

Comment: Then the example should test for the existence of the file, and you should not stub at all. I.e., `Dir.exist?(somefile).should be_true`

Comment: So even though I don't know where runner could be located, I should just make up an arbitrary location?

Comment: I'm testing a line that has `if Dir.glob("/opt/athena-*/bin/runner").any? then` so if I just do a `Dir.exist?` the test doesn't pass

Comment: Well if the specification is something like "the runner directory must exist", then your example will have be able to find it, right? Examples should test one thing and stub (or setup conditions for) the other dependencies. If the point of the test is to find a directory, your test should create it in the setup step and then find it in the spec. If the existence of the directory is just required for some other thing you are testing, then you should stub.

Comment: Maybe I'm still a little confused though...I'm testing this on a Windows machine but the rspec test is to see if it is on Linux.  So why would stubbing in a fake directory not work?

Comment: Clearly we are both confused! It looks like you are *not* testing that a directory exists--the directory listing is the dependency, not the subject. You want to know that the version number is correct. Correct? If so, create the files in directory or stub out the `Dir` calls, either way will work. You may need to stub `Dir.glob` as well -- you haven't shown us the code that calls `Dir.glob`, so we can't help you write that stub.

Comment: So currently I have code that read `Dir.stub(:glob).with(dir).and_return([mock_model(Dir, :'any' => true)])` which should stub the Dir.glob with the correct directory.  When I run that it appears that I get an error for `undefined method 'proxy_for'` which I am assuming comes from trying to use a mock_model inside of the stub?  Basically I need to stub the `Dir.glob` and then stub that it runs the command `any?` as well.  Is it a problem if I try it in one line?

Comment: You don't want `mock_model`--it is only for ActiveModel classes. A simple `double` should work. Or just return an array of strings for the directory name(s) you expect.

Comment: No idea I'm afraid. Is that on NilClass? Maybe this helps? https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/issues/746

Comment: I see. Someone passed on mock_model to me and I've only noticed more issues since. So if I even try to avoid the double and just do `Dir.stub(:glob).with{"/opt/athena-*/bin/runner"}.and_return(["opt/athena-1.5/bi‌​n/runner"])`, I'm still seeing this `undefined method 'proxy_for'` error. Where is that coming from?